# PDF page stored as what in bytes

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to write some script for work and I am having difficulty researching a particular question.  I assumed that each PDF page was an image, such as jpg, but even though I am reading the file it simply doesn't happen to be the case.  So my question is: What are the respective PDF pages stored as if not images?

Here is the code I am working work:

```
    pdf = user_file.file.read()
    startmark = b"\xff\xd8"
    startfix = 0
    endmark = b"\xff\xd9"
    endfix = 2
    i = 0

    njpg = 0
    while True:
        istream = pdf.find("stream", i)
        if istream < 0:
            break
        istart = pdf.find(startmark, istream, istream+20)
        if istart < 0:
            i = istream+20
            continue
        iend = pdf.find("endstream", istart)
        if iend < 0:
            raise Exception("Didn't find end of stream!")
        iend = pdf.find(endmark, iend-20)
        if iend < 0:
            raise Exception("Didn't find end of JPG!")

        istart += startfix
        iend += endfix
        print "JPG %d from %d to %d" % (njpg, istart, iend)
```

Comment: PDF is not that simple. Please look at http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf for reference. It's only about 700 pages. If you really want to do something real, use library. You can find example here https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167.

Answer (score -2):

PDFs should be stored as bytes I believe.
I used a library called [pypdf](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/41d90b4d141d0b019d145748f53ea556efcb47d1/Sample_Code/basic_features.py) when parsing my pdfs.

Comment: I believe every file is stored as bytes.

Comment: Yes... that's true, but I meant more like 'UTF-8' or opening the file with 'b' so to read it you would have to open a byte stream.

Comment: A file is nothing else than a sequence of bytes, possibly empty. So of course, you can read a PDF as bytes.